# Error while trying to get GPS location in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-location, android-gps

I have been following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNb_3QKSmMk&t=424s) to get GPS co-ordinates. Although this tutorial shows how to get the co-ordinates in an activity, I want to implement this in a swipe tab fragment.
In the Manifest file I have used the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Here is the Activity class:

```
public class SwipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}





public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Fragment1();
            case 1:
                return new Fragment2();
            case 2:
                return new Fragment3();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Here is the Fragment class in which I want to get the GPS co-ordinates:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {


TextView tv_gps;
Button gpsBtn;
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

public Fragment2() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filter, container, false);
    tv_gps = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_eventDemo);
    gpsBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_gps);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            tv_gps.append("\n"+location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET

            },10);

        }
        else{

        }
    }
    else {
        configureButton();
    }
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                configureButton();
                return;
            }
    }
}

private void configureButton() {
    gpsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Here, the line   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener); is giving an error even though I have handled the permission check above.

Can someone help me out please. Is there a better way to retrieve GPS co-ordinates in a fragment? I just want the co-ordinates to append to the textView once the Button is clicked.

Comment: `An error` is a broad statement. Won't compile? Runtime error? What does the Logcat say?

Comment: Logcat please?.